# How can I solve this integration numerically?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

how can I integrate this function numerically w.r.t `r` from 1 to 8, the function is as,

```
 1/(1 - 4 m /(r Sqrt[π]) {GammaRegularized[3/2, r^2/(4 θ)]}
```

Comment: Do you know `Integrate`? BTW, your equation does not make sense. Why did a list appear?

Comment: If `r` is a variable, you shouldn't use it as function: `(r [Sqrt][Pi])`

Comment: in this integration, r=1 is lower and r = 8 is upper limit

Answer (score 2):

To answer this ill-posed question, we need to know the following,

1. Values of `m` and `θ` which to do not produce a singularity in the integrand in the domain of interest, `{r, 1, 8}`. I choose `m = 20` and `θ = 4 π`, more or less arbitrarily.
2. A syntactically correct integrand. I am guessing you want

   ```
   1/(1 - 4 m/(r Sqrt[π]) GammaRegularized[3/2, r^2/(4 θ)])
   ```

With those choices, you can use [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) to get a value.

```
With[{m = 20, θ = 4 π}, 
  NIntegrate[1/(1 - 4 m/(r Sqrt[π]) GammaRegularized[3/2, r^2/(4 θ)]), {r, 1, 8}]]
```

> `-1.28077`

Note: you can **not** use square brackets `[ ]` or curly brackets `{ }` as higher-level parentheses in Mathematica.

Comment: @ravi. Great -- use whatever values that will row your boat.

Comment: @ravi. Don't ask an additional question as a comment to an answer. Post it as new question.